# Trigger Screensaver/Off monitor

Tags: screensaver, sleep, backlight

IS it possible to somehow trigger screensaver or make the monitor sleep/off? I want to disable screensaver/monitor sleep as it gets annoying at times, however I still want a way to save power via such methods

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sleep 1; xset dpms force off
```

source: http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/x-screen-blanking.html

You might find suspending the computer just as convenient.

Comment: Sometimes, I have things running in the background and dont want it to suspend

Comment: `sleep 1; xset dpms force off` works but is it possble to attach it to a launcher or keyboard shortcut? I tried creating a custom launcher and pasting in `sleep 1; xset dpms force off` in command but it does nothing

Comment: try `/bin/bash -c "sleep 1; xset dpms force off"` instead.

Comment: `~$ sleep 1; xset dpms force off`<br>
`~$ sleep 1; xset dpms force suspend`<br>
pity have two times the same HP Monitor Laptop has 1xVGA + 1xHDMI both commands set HDMI to sleep (LED from blue as active to orange as sleep) BUT the VGA driven Monitor keeps blue LED and on screen shows missing signal (not powering off).

Answer (score 2):

I figured after some searching in Google I can do

```
gnome-screensaver-command --activate
```

So I used it in a keytboard shortcut :)

UPDATE: hmm, the LCD backlight is still on, I guess what I really wanted is monitor off ...

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu 12.04 instructions**

1. Open System Settings from the menu
2. Click on Keyboard
3. Click the tab Shortcuts
4. Click on Custom Shortcuts
5. Click the little "+" icon to create a new shortcut
6. Both in name and command enter `xset dpms force off` , then click Apply
7. Click on your new shortcut where it says Disabled
8. Press the F12 key

This will set the F12 key to turn off your monitor. Press anything to turn it back on again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to put the monitor to sleep manually.

The closest thing I can suggest is to set the Power Management Preferences to put the display to sleep at the minimum time of one minute, then use the 'Inhibit Applet' on the Gnome Panel to disable sleep manually.

When you start the computer, click the applet to keep the monitor on. When you are ready to put the monitor to sleep, click it and the display will shut off a minute later.

Not very elegant but it's what you are wanting, with a one-minute delay. Hopefully someone else has a better response.

Comment: Hi I found that `/etc/acpi/screenblank.sh` can be used but I get an error ... so it offs the LCD then truns in back on ... `awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (missing '('):0)`

Answer (score 0):

Running `gnome-screensaver-command -a` will trigger the screensaver.

Comment: hmm I found that somewhere too, but I now thing what I really wanted is make the monitor sleep manually, as screensaver will not off backlight